# is it possible to deploy a simple java web application to a local server using gitlab-ci without docker?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm simply trying to copy the war to the webapps folder of my tomcat and restart the server, something like

```
copy /y .\WebAppFolder\target\WebApp*.war C:\server\webapps\ROOT.war
```

He can't find this specified path when try to copy, but locally this command works.
My runner is on windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was trying to use the "target" created by the previous stage, but the runner deletes everything that is not tracked at the end of each stage.
I add this code in the stage was generate the war so the runner does not destroy the directory

```
artifacts:
    untracked: true
    paths:
        - WebApp/target
```

Getting something like that

```
buildWebApp:maven:
   stage: buildWebApp
   tags: 
     - tag
   script: mvn clean install -f WebApp/pom.xml
   artifacts:
     untracked: true
     paths:
        - WebApp/target
   only: 
     - master


test:
   stage: test
   tags: 
      - tag
   script: 
      - copy /y my copy
      - mvn test -f testes/pom.xml
   only: 
      - master
```

Sorry but i lost the link of gitlab doc where i find this solution